# String null when getting text from JTextField

Tags: java, eclipse, string, jtextfield, jtextarea

Ok I edited the original post so no one is going to argue on the title again (and that's my fault, so don't get mad now)...
I have a portion of code that takes the text of a TextField (there are two TextFields actually, but the user can use only one at a time) and search it into a file stored into the terminal. The problem is that I always get a null string, even when there is text into one of the TextFields...
This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Search implements ActionListener{
JFrame frame;
JButton click;
JLabel comando, carico;
JTextField textv, text;
JTextArea res;
String pathFile = "C:\\Log.txt";
String str= new String();

Search(){

    frame = new JFrame("Search");
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1));
    click = new JButton("Cerca");
    comando = new JLabel("Comando");
    carico = new JLabel("A carico di:");
    textv = new JTextField("");
    text = new JTextField("");
    res = new JTextArea("");
    panel.add(comando);
    panel.add(textv);
    panel.add(carico);
    panel.add(text);
    panel.add(click);
    res.setLineWrap(true);
    res.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    res.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(res);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    panel.add(scroller);
    frame.add(panel);
    click.addActionListener(this);      
    click.setSize(70, 35);      
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==click){
        res.setText(null);
        if(textv != null) {cercaStringa(pathFile, textv.getText().toString());}
        else {cercaStringa(pathFile, text.getText().toString());}
    }
}

public void cercaStringa(String pathFile, String stringa){
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile));
        String line = new String();
        while((line = in.readLine())!=null) {   
            if(line.contains(stringa)){
                res.append(line);
                res.append("\n");
                }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
    }



public static void main (String[] args){
    new Search();
}
```

}

I'm really going to throw everything outside the window cause I know the solution is simple but I can't get it...

Comment: Sorry everyone... forgot to put a "HELLO" at the beginning xD

Comment: What's the value of `str`?

Comment: Then please close your question.

Comment: what is `res` and where is declared? Looks like it needs cleared on entry to the method.

Comment: `String.contains` does work; it's your code that doesn't work.

Comment: `res` is most likely a `JTextArea` (res for result).

Comment: it looks like now is a fine day to learn how to use the java debugger

Comment: res is a TextArea and str contains the string that the user wants to search

Answer (score 6):

The only value of `str` that is guaranteed to always give `true` for `line.contains(str)` is the empty `String`.

---

(You should assume that the `String.contains` method DOES work according to its specification.  The chance of a previously undetected bug in a method so central to Java SE is negligible, especially a bug that is as spectacular as you are suggesting.  Certainly, claiming that it is broken without any solid evidence is only going to waste everyone's time ... and especially yours.)

Comment: *"claiming that it is broken without any solid evidence is only going to waste everyone's time ... and especially yours"* +1

Comment: Ok let's clarify some points:

 - First of all I'm not claiming anything. "String.contains doesn't work" doesn't mean that the method is bugged or something like that. It means that IN THIS CASE it doesn't work for this or that question. Try to think before accusing...

Comment: - Second thing: res is a TextArea in which I'm supposed to put the results. str instead is a simple string that contains the word that the user wants to search...
 - Third thing: I debugged it, tried and tried again. The weird thing is that if I put the first read into the while (as in the code above) every single line in the file is written into the TextArea, so string.contains "doesn't work"; instead if I put the read into the loop, modifying the while (while(in.readLine!=null)) Eclipse gives me the NullPointerException...

Comment: @LeonGuerrero - "It means that IN THIS CASE it doesn't work for this".  Actually, it DOES work in this case.  The problem is that you are using it incorrectly ... somehow ... or misinterpretting the evidence.  Frankly, I don't trust the evidence you are describing to us.  It is implausible.  Something else is going on that you haven't explained ... or haven't noticed.  And since I can't sit next to you and see the real source code, the debugger ouput, etc, I cannot help any further.

Comment: @StephenC you're still assuming that I'm pointing fingers to the method... I wrote that phrase cause I had nothing else in mind... THE METHOD (string.contains()) works fine. It's the CODE that doesn't work. I'm sorry if I caused some misunderstanding but I thought the title was just indicative... I edited the entire post anyway...